# How to list the records from different tables inside cshtml view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, razor

I am having a problem in a ASP.NET MVC project. I have a database where I have several tables, and I want to list all the records inside each table in my View, I am able to do this using only one table, I am going to provide here the code that works with one table and what I am trying to do.

**Controller:**

Using only one table I would do:

```
Mp5DataclassesDataContext db = new Mp5DataclassesDataContext();
public ActionResult Admin()
{
    return View(db);
}
```

This is what I am trying to do:

```
    return View(db);
```

At this point I can debug and see that all my tables are in that db object, with all the correct data. Then the problem is in my View

**View:**

```
@*This is defined at the top of my .cshtml*@
@model IEnumerable<Interface_AutoUtad.Models.Mp5DataclassesDataContext>

@*This is the code that works with only one table*@
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.table_column)
}

@*What I am trying to do:*@
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.some_other_table.table_column)
}
```

I can't get this last part to work because "some_other_table" doesn't show up.
Is there a way I can achieve this ? I want to Iterate through each table and inside iterate through each record in that table.

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: Can you share the code of your model classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've set the "model" for your view to be your application's `DbContext`. Don't do that. Views are only processed at runtime, and querying into your database is *way* too much logic for a view. Any errors will only be exposed at runtime, and you have a huge potential for errors.

Views are designed to work with only one type. If you need to work with multiple types in the same view, you can either utilize a view model or use child actions.

### View Model

```
public class MultipleTypesViewModel()
{
    public IEnumerable<SomeType> SomeTypes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OtherType> OtherTypes { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@model Namespace.To.MultipleTypesViewModel

...

@foreach (var item in Model.SomeTypes)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.table_column)
}

@foreach (var item in Model.OtherTypes)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.table_column)
}

...
```

### Child Actions

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult ListSomeTypes()
{
    var someTypes = db.SomeTypes.ToList();
    return PartialView(someTypes);
}

[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult ListOtherTypes()
{
    var otherTypes = db.OtherTypes.ToList();
    return PartialView(otherTypes);
}

...
```

Then, create an appropriate partial view for each:

**ListSomeTypes.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Namespace.To.SomeType>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.table_column)
}
```

**ListOtherTypes.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Namespace.To.OtherType>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.table_column)
}
```

Etc. And then finally in your main view:

```
@Html.Action("ListSomeTypes")
@Html.Action("ListOtherTypes")
```

(In this case, the model of the main view is totally irrelevant.)

Comment: Hi there Chris! I can't thank you enough for the code it worked like a charm! Thank you for spending your time to help me with my problem.